# How to determine the lat long of a point in the atmosphere which is 250 km altitude?

Tags: geodetic

Regarding determination of coordinates of Ionospheric Pierce Point (IPP)

[image: sketch]

S is the position of a geostationary satellite. E is the elevation angle.

The radio signal coming from the satellite s penetrates the IPP point and received at location whose lat long are 16.8 N and 74.2 E.

We need to find the coordinates (lat, long) of a point (IPP) which is in the atmosphere.

We need the latitude and longitude of that point, which is called the ionospheric pierce point (IPP).

Comment: You can check the 2 PDFs for the formula.   http://www.gpstk.org/foswiki/pub/Documentation/GPSTkPublications/GaussiranBeaconGPSTK.pdf  and https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiK_cev8pHQAhXKsY8KHZjXDEAQFggeMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffile.PostFileLoader.html%3Fid%3D56bc281b5dbbbdd2a08b4569%26assetKey%3DAS%253A327827653185536%25401455171611691&usg=AFQjCNFwSpscXOSrX2GuicCDD7jNugri1g&sig2=xNE3O7li0xYYcVy7VvtWbQ&bvm=bv.137904068,d.c2I&cad=rja